# How to easily add flight itinerary to Google Calendar from flight confirmation email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I got an email from my colleague about our business itinerary containing flight confirmation as a PDF attachment. Turns out Google can detect that it's a flight confirmation.

When I search 'itinerary' in Google it shows something like this.

[image: screen shot of flight information]

My question is, is there a way to add this info to my Google Calendar? (I want the flight schedule to be shown in my Sunrise app in my iPhone)

Comment: Tripit.com can do this for you.

Comment: I confirmed with Expedia.ca customer service that customers must do this by hand (they apologized for the inconvenience). Next time, I'll try another service, since there's not much difference in price.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to add a flight number in google calendar and have the event auto update based on the flight feed.

Comment: In my case, Google parses the events perfectly. Why then not provide an Add Event button is proof that they are only human.

Comment: Sometimes the events are created as soon as the email comes in, but then deleted a few minutes later. I was even able to restore the event from the calendar *Trash* and restore from there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To add any email event to your Google Calendar...

Web mail version:

Open the web version email, Click on the "More" icon (3 vertical dots to the right of the "Labels" icon) in the Top toolbar menu, then select "Create event".

Make sure you are clicking on the GMail "More" icon above and not the "more" (3 dots) inside the Email header.

Mobile version:

ONE TIME: 
Open Settings in the Mobile Calendar app. Open "Events from Gmail". Turn this setting ON for your email address. Set visibility if applicable.

Sometimes Gmail copies all the event details you need into the calendar event description.

Depending upon how well Gmail reads the PDF file (or email), you may have to copy / paste the details from the original to the Calendar event.

Comment: I just tried this, but the event created did not have the correct day or time.

Comment: Google is not able to pull dates and times for all formats.  You may have to double check these when you create the event.  In most cases, not all.

Comment: Gmail displays the flight ticket header on top of the e-ticket confirmations e-mail, however, "Create event" doesn't appear in the "More" menu...

Comment: If the More.. menu does not have the option, this means that the dates were not readable for whatever reason.  This does happen from time to time.  In these cases the only way is to go to Calendar and copy / paste the content of the email and edit accordingly.

Comment: This does not seem to work as of October 2018. There is no 'more'. There is three vertical dots sign in the right corner, but it has no 'create event' as far as i can see

Comment: It's there, but in the "more" options menu in the top toolbar, not the one that's on the right hand side of the email body

Comment: Unfortunately, the "more" at the top of the toolbar seems to just unintelligently pull content out of the email and create an event happening today.

Comment: Yes, it creates an event not only for today but for now / soon, which is completely stupid since the mail is correctly parsed to make a header above the email.

Comment: @RobbieAverill not in the top toolbar for me - https://i.imgur.com/2wHdvHH.png (Chrome on Win10)

Comment: In the top toolbar for me, but still a pity it does not auto-fill correct information, only 'soon'/'today'.  Even moreso since popular event services at least craft their own links and downloads that allow you to add prepared events easily to your calendar.  Make sure you are looking for the menu that would correspond to the entire message stream, and not the toolbar for a single email.

Comment: Gmail now has a 'View in Travel' option, use it to show details and forward it to another email makes it show in Google calendar correctly for me.

Answer (score 18):

Send an email with subject line "Flight Itinerary" to yourself and copy-paste the contents of Itinerary PDF into the email as a plain text. Google will automatically parse this new email and add the event to your calendar now.

Comment: Worked for me -- Nice! An even easier way: Just FORWARD the email to yourself and edit the subject to include "Flight Itinerary". No need to copy-paste into a new email as long as you delete the "FROM: ...." and "TO: ...." at the top of the forwarded email.

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: Did not work with an American Airlines itinerary for me.

Comment: @AustinD, that deserves a new answer.

Comment: Try pasting the entire content of a HTML or PDF when sending the email. Copy-pasting just the itinerary didn't work but entire content worked.

Comment: @AustinD working in 2022, thank you

Comment: This works for me as of 2022, but only when sending between two email addresses and not directly from my address to itself. Used my partners email account and this worked like a charm.

Comment: I have a PDF of Etihad itinerary. I sent it from another email to my Gmail, copied contents into text, attached PDF -nothing works. Anyone got it to work for Etihad? Also, is calendar supposed to show it instantly? I waited several minutes and reloaded page too.

Comment: Even I tried everything in the comments. Nit working for me in 2023

Answer (score 5):

Since I don't like how Gmail's "Create Event" scrapes the information into a calendar event (it can show the proper header in the email but creates a calendar event for today?) I use Kayak's Trips feature. I can just forward the flight confirmation emails to a Kayak email address and it automatically (and correctly) creates the calendar events in a calendar feed that I can then use in Google Calendar. If you set up a filter in Gmail to automatically forward the flight confirmation emails to Kayak it can be a set it and forget it process. Yes, it's a few more steps to set up but I find this way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure out the same thing, I found that the dates and times are clickable, leading to an "add to calendar" pop up window, which posts the event in Google calendar. This might depend, of course, on the format of the travel itinerary sent by every company.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I got a flight booking confirmation sent to my email. Google added the flights to the Calendar, but for some reason, after a couple of days they disappeared.

I forwarded the same email to myself without even changing the subject or anything, and it just came back to my calendar, so it might be just worth trying to forward the confirmation to your email again.